# How can I get the default Ubuntu boot logo back after returning from using Xubuntu?

Tags: unity, xubuntu

I installed xubuntu-desktop and starting using the xfce based desktop after a falling out with unity. Now I've returned to using the unity desktop but I'm left with the xubuntu boot screens. How can I remove/change them back to the defaults?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to restore the original behaviour by reconfiguring the plymouth theme(s), using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

and

```
sudo update-alternatives --config text.plymouth
```

and select the respective Ubuntu alternatives from the menu provided.. Alternatively you could remove the corresponding package completely, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xubuntu-plymouth-theme
```